# Can't set member data when nested in a class

Tags: c++, class, nested, setter

I'm having this issue on another program, but I tried to simplify it with this one. I cannot set the weapon name through p.getWeaopn().setName("sword"); It works fine when I simply set it through its own object, but when I try to access the setter through player it doesn't set anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Weapon.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Player p; // Player contains only a Weapon weapon;
    Weapon w; // Weapon only contains a string name;

    //w.setName("sword"); // this changes the name of the weapon

    p.setWeapon(w);

    p.weapon.setName("sword"); // this also changes the name

    p.getWeapon().setName("sword"); // this is not setting the name. Why?

    // checking if weapon has a name

    if (p.getWeapon().getName().empty())
    {
        cout << "Weapon name is empty!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Weapon name is " << p.getWeapon().getName() << endl;
    }
}
```

Weapon.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Weapon
{
private:
    string name;
public:
    string getName();
    void setName(string);
};
```

Weapon.cpp

```
#include "Weapon.h"

string Weapon::getName()
{
    return name;
}
void Weapon::setName(string n)
{
    name = n;
}
```

Player.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Weapon.h"

class Player
{
private:
    Weapon weapon;

public:

    Weapon getWeapon();
    void setWeapon(Weapon);
};
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"

Weapon Player::getWeapon()
{
    return weapon;
}
void Player::setWeapon(Weapon w)
{
    weapon = w;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve] we have no idea what `getWeapon()` `setName()` etc do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Weapon Player::getWeapon()
```

You return a copy and not a reference of the weapon, so any change to the copy does not affect the original.

For return a reference, use `&` operator:

```cpp
Weapon& Player::getWeapon()
{
    return this->weapon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Player::getWeapon() returns a copy of the weapon every time instead of a reference to the weapon. Changing the name in the copy changes nothing in the original.

Comment: It should be a comment

Comment: Sorry, I saw your answer before, then it was gone, so I answered after the additional code examples confirmed the issue.

Comment: This is a valid answer, although not very long